# Minecraft launcher started showing desktop paint buffers

Tags: window-manager

[image]

This launcher had been working yesterday, but now it only shows a static clip of the background from where the window opened.

For some reason, the background is painting on top of the content inside the window.

I feel like this is part of opacity features??

How can I get the background to stop painting inside the minecraft launcher window?

Answer (score 0):

The first solution I found was to make sure the window started off in the top left corner of the screen.  But this quickly failed.  Then someone on reddit offered this solution:

Go to:

`$ nano /usr/share/applications/minecraft-launcher.desktop`

then edit:

`Exec=env GTK_CSD=0 minecraft-launcher`

---

Alternatively, running `$ env GTK_CSD=0 minecraft-launcher` will also work